# upload images from s3 bucket

Tags: magento2

I'm uploading product images to s3 bucket and I need to import products from csv.

So I set `Images File Directory` to be `https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/image-folders/`, But I got hat error

```
1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: check this - https://github.com/thaiphan/magento-s3

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem like you.
I found the problem come from the checking after on local after upload file. The fix is very simple. You can see my fixed here.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20761/commits/8612789375b0c173f0ba852c587882af6ff8bc7f